# Many errors when trying to load and work with json in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, python-3.7

I have tried using .read() and .decode("utf-8") just keep getting errors like this 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str'

```
from requests import get
import json

url = 'http://taco-randomizer.herokuapp.com/random/?full-taco=true'
requested_taco = get(url)
requested_taco_data = json.loads(requested_taco.read())
title = requested_taco_data['name']
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help me figure out how to get the json to become a dictionary in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `response.read()` in Requests, instead you should use `response.json()` like so:

```
taco = requested_taco.json()
print(taco['name'])
```

which would output:

```
'Black Bean, Potato, and Onion Tacos'
```

no need for json library.